# Прибавить к текущей дате время

Tags: php

На сайте wordpress пытаюсь вывести в карточке товара "Ближайшую дату доставки".
Она должна складываться так: Текущее время + время доставки (произвольное поле) + время изготовления букета (произвольное поле), что только не перепробовала, не сильна я в этом:

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$a = the_field('время_доставки','option');
echo date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime("+".$a." minutes"));?>
```

Выводит только произвольное поле(((
Что не так?

Comment: а что у Вас в $a? там точно количество минут?

Comment: да, там 60 минут

Comment: а можно с выводом ознакомиться? что значит: 'только произвольное поле'? У меня команда 'echo date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('+ 5  minutes'));' выводит '01.06.2020 10:48'

Comment: https://prnt.sc/srlv0g вот, что он мне выводит, сначала "60" - это количество минут в поле, а потом дату оч далекую...

Comment: а когда конкретно ставлю цифру, как вы говорите "('+ 5 minutes'))" - то все замечательно работает, не спорю

Comment: очень странно. 'date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow'); $a = 60; echo date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime("+".$a." minutes")); ' => 01.06.2020 14:52

Comment: я только на значение $a грешу.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/srm285 - вот поле в админке указано, я только в вопросе название поля укоротила, да и на предыдущем скрине оно выводится перед датой - "60"

Comment: и всё-же выведите var_dump($a) сразу после получения. мало ли чего там может произойти?

Comment: ошибка оказалась в другом:

Comment: <?php
$a = get_field('время_доставки','option');
echo date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime("+".$a." minutes"));?>

Comment: вместо the_field надо было get_field

Comment: в любом случае спасибо за помощь)

Comment: я же с первого комментария говорил, что дело в $a, но, в любом случае, спасибо, что не послали))